# Convergence of a Net: Example

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

**Context**

I'd like to give my own specific sense to:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}U_t=U_0$$
for a unitary group $U_t$.

**Problem**

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies:
$$f(t_n)\to c$$
for all sequences $s:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}:n\mapsto t_n$ with $t_n\to a$ for $n\to\infty$.

Then, how to prove that:
$$f(t)\to c$$
for the special net $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:t\mapsto t$ with the ordering $t'\geq t:\Leftrightarrow|t'-a|\leq|t-a|$

**Attempt**

I guess its about the real line being second countable so especially first countable.
Or does it have to do something with cofinality? Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with this concept yet so I thought this could be a nice example for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first condition says that $f$ is Heine-continuous at $a$ with value $c$. Your second condition is equivalent to the statement that $f$ is continuous at $a$ with value $c$ (using $ε$-$δ$ definition).

Continuity implies Heine-continuity since continous function preserve convergence (also pointwise).

For the other implication, note that continuity of $f$ at $x$ is equivalent to topological property $x ∈ \overline{A} \implies f(x) ∈ f[\overline{A}]$. Let $X$ be a topological space, define $C: \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ as $C(A) := \text{“limits of all sequences with values in $A$”}$ for $A ⊆ X$. $C$ may be called Fréchet closure operator on $X$. Note that $C(A) ⊆ \overline{A}$ for $A ⊆ X$. Any function $f$ which is Heine-continuous at $x$ is also Fréchet-continous at $x$, meaning $x ∈ C(A) \implies f(x) ∈ f[C(A)]$. Finally, on Fréchet spaces (those where $C(A) = \overline{A}$ for $A ⊆ X$), we have that Fréchet continuity at a point implies continuity at that point.

The class of Fréchet spaces includes all first-countable spaces as one can construct a sequence $S ⊆ A$ with $S \to x$ whenever $x ∈ \overline{A}$ using the countable basis at $x$. So it is because real line is first countable. And there is also a connection with cofinality since the topology on the real line is order topology and the order on the real line has countable cofinality from both sides at each point.